# Does dd bs setting affect the output image when there is input/output error?

Tags: linux, dd

Suppose I run the command:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/home/user/image.img conv=noerror bs=4M
```

During the run of `dd`, there are Input/output errors due to read issue of `/dev/sda` (with error message *dd: error reading
'/dev/sda': Input/output error*), but `conv=noerror` allows `dd` to continue past errors.

My question is whether the `bs` setting affects what is written in the output image file. The `bs` setting is about the size of chunk being read from the disk, and if the chunk contains read error, does `dd` simply fill zeros to bits that cannot be read and copy rest of the chunk as it is? Or does `dd` simply write zeros for the copied chunk?

Comment: @pLumo so is it that if one has bs=4M and encounters an error in the 4M chunk, that means the 4M chunk being written would be filled with zeros in case of dd - and one should use ddrescue to prevent it?

Comment: This is what the answer says. I guess it is correct, yes.